# When does $a^b\mid b^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b >1$ be integers. When does $a^b \mid b^a$?

<s>Certainly if this is true then $a\mid b$  by considering $a$'s prime factors.</s>  (not quite convinced).
Also then if $b$ is prime then $a=b$.

There the well know solution to the problem $x^y=y^x$, which tells that $2^4=4^2$ is the only solution given the conditions.

I've a feeling this might be the only other case.

Comment: We can find solutions by letting $a$ and $b$ be suitable powers of $p$. There is lots of slack.

Comment: Look at the prime factors of a and b.

Comment: @AndréNicolas nice hint. So would any powers of primes do? If I took $a=p^m$ and $b=p^n$, then if $a\neq b$ and $p \neq 2$, then either $a^b \mid b^a$ or $b^a \mid a^b$? Just by considering which is bigger.

Comment: @snulty: Yes, and $2$ is barely an exception, we know the only case of equality when $m\ne n$.